# Assigning values to all images found by class in Jquery

Tags: jquery

So I have to pull all images that are in a slideshow and print out different messages depending on what number they are in the slideshow. So currently I have the following:

```
$('.image-class img').click(function() {
    console.log("hi");
});
```

Lets pretend the html is something like tihs

```
<ul>
<li class="image-class"><img src="image1.png" /></li>
<li class="image-class"><img src="image2.png" /></li>
<li class="image-class"><img src="image3.png" /></li>
</ul>
```

So currently it finds all of the images then when I click one it prints "hi" to the console. It works exactly as I Intended. I'm just stuck as to how to print for example "Image 1" when image one is clicked and "Image 2" when the second image is clicked. I need this to work for any potential number of slides that are added to the slideshow.

Any help would be appreciated. If you need anymore information let me know!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$(this)` to access your clicked image object Like.

```
$('.image-class img').click(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('src'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get to the attributes of the currently selected item like so:

```
$('.image-class img').click(function () {
   var text = $(this).attr("src");
   console.log(text);
});
```